# Pedal arm clunking & falling off, how to fix?

Tags: maintenance

The pedal arm on the opposite side from the cogs is making a 'thunk' sound once per cycle when near the top. It has come off twice, with no apparent thread or bolt damage. Both times the arm has come loose a bit before falling off, though I assume this is because the bolt is loose not something else. What is happening & how do i fix it & what tools do I need? Is this cheap enough to make it worthwhile?

I assume that there's something wrong with the... (bearing cassette? Not sure of terminology here, the round bit that holds the bearings in place) or the bearings themselves. Is there anything else it could be?

I have the bike equivalent of an old banger. Looking to fix it up well enough to sell on cheap, hence looking for a cheap fix. I'm capable diyer  but without recent bike maintainence experience (like, I dismantled & regreased bearings 20y ago but nowt since). I'm currently a student so I have free time but almost no money.

Comment: What kind of crank is it? Is the axle that it's attached to square? By the way, it's great that you're fixing the bike instead of taking the money and running.

Comment: I think with square taper cranksets the consensus is that the crankarm and spindle surfaces are irreparably damaged once it’s come loose and continued to be ridden that way. You could still try to salvage with threadlocker on the bolt threads and retaining compound (e.g. Loctite 648) on the surfaces.

Comment: This is all really helpful. Yes it is a square taper. This all rings true. There is a community bike scheme in Bristol, but it sounds like I will probably donate my bike to it rather than request parts from it. Thank you all!

Comment: I don't fully agree. Square taper are made of much stronger stuff than most cheap crankset, so there's a non-negligible chance the square taper is fine. (in which case, a valid arm from a bike store's spare parts bin should be quite cheap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guessing you have a "square taper" axle, and the crank is held to the axle by either a nut or a bolt?

You might be tempted to put some torque on the bolt, but most of the work is done by the taper mating up closely.

If you inspect the taper inside and outside surfaces, I bet there will be rounding and distortion from being ridden loose.  This is a self-aggrevating  condition where it gets worse because it is already bad.

Your proper fix would be a new bottom bracket cartridge, and a new crank arm.  But that's money for parts and tools.

It may be possible to find a donor bike (LEGALLY!!) and get the parts you need off that, but still needs tools.

Some cities have a bike cooperative that helps people get their bikes working again.  Search and ask about - council and library websites can be useful.

Your budget fixes are generally not going to be permanent.

1. Use a file to smooth off bumps, maintaining the same angles.  Recover enough of the taper and the parts will grip each other better.
2. Lubricate the taper lightly before refitting the crank.
3. Locktite or threadlocker on the nut/bolt.  Be aware you're not getting this off again easily
4. Torque - with the other fixes this should help

In the past I've seen people weld cranks on, and generally it fails.  There is a lot of leverage, and dissimilar metal welds do not cope for long.

Last resort is get another beater bike and combine both.   Good luck !

Comment: +1. The good news is that a new square taper bottom bracket only costs ~11€. New crankset starts at ~50€ but you can probably find a used one in good shape. The biggest problem will be getting (free or cheap) access to the necessary, specialized tools.

Comment: In many cases (confirmed by my experience and the LBS that fixed it for me when it happened), the square taper is much stronger than the crank arm, and so only the arm gets damaged. In that case, no need to replace bottom bracket. Replacing the left crank arm is super cheap (and doesn't require any special tool, if it's already fallen out) - if you don't care about an exact match with the right side. (Just make sure you get the same length, which in most cases will be 170mm)

Comment: @njzk2 yep - noone can see both sides of the bike at the same time, so mismatched crank arms can be hard to notice.